# JQuery - Dynamic Text Trimming - Iphone issue

Tags: jquery, iphone

We are implementing a mobile version of a clients website.  A store page has a long list of store information with links to further info an example of one store HTML block is as follows -

```
 <div class="overlayContent">
<h2>Bagot Opticians</h2>
<div>
10 Library Road
<br>
Kendal, LA9 4QB
<br>
Tel: 01539 721619
</div>
<a href="store-directory/bagot-opticians.aspx">more about S., C. &amp; T. Bagot</a>
</div>
```

I have used the following code to loop through the stores and remove the 'more about part of the text:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {



$('.jsGrid ul li').each(function(index) {
     var anchortext =($('.overlayContent a', this).text());
     alert(anchortext)

        $('.overlayContent a', this).html(anchortext.substring(10, anchortext.length));

});
});
```

it works fine on every device apart from an iphone - which for some reason picks up the tel number as  part of the a target!?  Can anyone offer a different approach or any reason for this issue?

Cheers
Paul

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.jsGrid ul li').each(function(index) {
    $('.overlayContent a', this).remove();
  });
});
```

Replace remove() with empty() if you want to keep the  element itself but just empty it.